# How to obtain a fadeout effect using canvas 2D context javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was wondering how to obtain a specific fadeout effect on a javascript 2D canvas (I've already seen some answers detailing how to create such fadeouts, but none matched what I want to do).

I have several canvases that are stacked on top of one another, each one corresponding to a specific fadeout duration. The goal was initially to display figures on a choosen layer depending on the desired fadeout duration, so that I could have several fadeout times in one scene.

I then drew at each tick and on each canvas a full `rgb(255, 255, 255, a)` rectangle (with `a` depending on the fadeout duration, and thus on the canvas), so that elements of a specific canvas will gradually disappear ; but this also hides the canvases beneath it, so that only the top layer is visible.

My question is : is there some method of `CanvasRenderingContext2D` (or an equivalent way to achieve that) that allows to simply increase the alpha value of everything contained in the canvas without drawing anything on it (I insist on that point, if anything (even something that's white) stays permanently on the canvas it will hide the lower layers) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So you want to apply alpha without losing the image, right?

Well given...

```
var C=document.getElementById('canvas');
```

If it’s a single value alpha to be applied throughout the image then it’s quite easy to do with...

```
var Cx=C.getContext('2d');

Cx.globalAlpha=0.75;

Cx.fillRect(0,0,C.width,C.height);
```

But if it's varying levels of alpha depending on the pixel then we have to loop through all pixels like this...

```
 var Cx=C.getContext('2d');

 var Data=Cx.getImageData(0,0,C.width,C.height), D=Data.data, L=D.length;
    
 for(var i=0; i<L; i+=4){
    
  D[i+3]=???   // <-- Insert logic here to apply varying levels of alpha for each pixel 
     
  if(i==(L-4)){Cx.putImageData(Data,0,0);}

 }
```